# How to CORS Allow Headers in Sails

Tags: javascript, express, routes, cors, sails.js

I want my server to allow 'Authorization' header for my mobile app. Currently my webserver is in sails and I use sails. My routes code is

```
'post /auth/local' : {
    cors: {
       origin: '*'    
    },
    controller: 'AuthController',
    action: 'callback'
},
```

When my client sends a request with 'Authorization' in header I get error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1337/auth/local. 
Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

How do I specify in my routes code that 'Authorization' header is also allowed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `headers : 'Content-Type, Authorization'` to `cors` object, like example below:

```
'post /auth/local' : {
    cors: {
       origin: '*',
       headers: 'Content-Type, Authorization'  
    },
    controller: 'AuthController',
    action: 'callback'
},
```

> headers: Comma-delimited list of headers that are allowed to be sent with CORS requests. This is only used in response to [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Source: [Sails CORS Config](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-cors)

Notice that `Content-Type` is also required due is the default value of that property and is required for POST and PUT methods.

Comment: How do I make this true for all the routes at one go?

Comment: Use `cors: true` and [config.cors.js](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-cors),  setup [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors).Regards.